# Cannot run console c# application built with CMake

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake

I've the following source (main.cs)

```
using System;

namespace csexec
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int i = 0;
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
  }

}
```

And the following `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14.0)

project(csexec VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)

include(CSharpUtilities)

set(PROJECT_SRC
  main.cs
)

add_executable(csexec ${PROJECT_SRC})

set_property(TARGET csexec PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")
set_property(TARGET csexec PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
set_property(TARGET csexec PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "Microsoft.CSharp"
    "PresentationCore"
    "PresentationFramework"
    "System"
    "System.Core"
    "System.Data"
    "System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
    "System.Net.Http"
    "WindowsBase")
```

I'm using CMake with Viual Studio. This is the `CMakeSettings.json`:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x64-Debug",
      "generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "msvc_x64_x64"
      ],
      "buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/build",
      "installRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/install",
      "cmakeExecutable": "C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE",
          "value": "H:/Projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
          "type": "PATH"
        },
        {
          "name": "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET",
          "value": "x64-windows",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-Release",
      "generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64",
      "configurationType": "Release",
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "msvc_x64_x64"
      ],
      "buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/build",
      "installRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/build/vs2019/install",
      "cmakeExecutable": "C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin\\cmake.exe",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "variables": [
        {
          "name": "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE",
          "value": "H:/Projects/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
          "type": "PATH"
        },
        {
          "name": "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET",
          "value": "x64-windows",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The project is generated and build in Visual Studio without problems, but when I run it from the console the `Hello World` message does not appear. If I run it from Visual Studio by putting a break-point in that line it does not break. I presume that I need to specify the entry point for the application.

What I can do in order to print the message and make the application fully functional?

Comment: Perhaps, it is fact that you have `WIN32_EXECUTABLE` set, but you have the rest of your configuration for a 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Thanks, removing that parameter solved the issue. If you make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this problem before also. From the CMake documentation for the [`WIN32_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html) target property:

> When this property is set to true the executable when linked on Windows will be created with a WinMain() entry point instead of just main(). This makes it a GUI executable instead of a console application.

This parameter is typically used for creating WinForms or WPF C#-based applications, but not console applications. In addition, it conflicts with 64-bit architecture settings in your `CMakeSettings.json` configuration file. In your case, you probably do not need this property setting, and removing should resolve the issue.

Comment: small note, WIN32 has nothing to do with 32-bit application, it's just the name for Windows executables.